# CloudFront to a public or private Route53 hosted zone

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have an ALB created with Terraform and a CloudFront Distribution which is so old that it's not managed by Terraform. My ALB was given a random number in the DNS name and I have concerns about entering this ALB DNS as Origin in CloudFront.

So my idea was, to setup a Route53 entry that would be more or less fixed and also managed via Terraform. But I haven't found a way so far that CloudFront will point to my Route53 hosted zone. Therefore I ask if a registered domain is necessary.

Is it possible that a CloudFront Origin points to a Route53 entry without a domain being registered, i.e. only to private or public hosted zone entries?

Comment: Can you maybe add an example to tell us what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Maurice I have an ALB created with Terraform and a CloudFront Distribution which is so old an not managed by Terraform. My ALB was given a random number in the DNS name and I have concerns about entering this ALB DNS as Origin in CloudFront. So my idea was, to setup a Route53 entry that would be more or less fixed and also managed via Terraform. But I haven't found a way so far that CloudFront will point to my Route53 hosted zone. Therefore I ask if a registered domain is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's something I can answer - I've edited your question to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be concerned about the longevity of the DNS name of your ALB.
The DNS name of your ALB is static as long as your ALB exists. If you delete it, you'll get a new one, but as long as it stays, it will be static.

So if you don't plan to periodically delete your ALB, I'd be perfectly comfortable using it's DNS name as the origin in CloudFront.

---

**About your DNS questions:**

You can also add an ALIAS or CNAME record in a **public hosted zone** that points to your ALB (or it's DNS name in case of CNAME), which is managed by Terraform.
It has to be a public hosted zone with a real domain, i.e. some zone must be delegated through DNS to Route53.
Remember that you'll have to create a SSL/TLS certificate for this to work.
Afterwards you could set up the custom domain name as the origin in CloudFront.
This requires you to have a (sub-)domain that is delegated to your public hosted zone.

You **can't** do the same with a **private hosted zone** though.
CloudFront needs a DNS name it can resolve and since CloudFront is not part of your VPC, it needs a publicly resolvable DNS name, which the private hosted zone doesn't provide.

Comment: "You seem to be concerned about the longevity of the DNS name of your ALB." exactly

Comment: "Remember that you'll have to create a SSL/TLS certificate for this to work." Why is a certificate necessary?

Comment: Because I sincerely hope you encrypt your users traffic to your backend ;-)

Comment: Somehow that doesn't work for me.
I have a LoadBalancer DNS that gives me 100% 200 as a status code. 
Then I created a completely new CloudFront distribution and entered the record name of type A from my public hosted zone as Origin. 
"Value / Route traffic to" is "dualstack.<DNS_NAME>". But the request does not arrive. Are you sure that this can work? Does CloudFront check the name servers of the AWS account first?

Comment: I get a 502 "CloudFront wasn't able to resolve the origin domain name. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner."

Comment: FYI: Setting the ALB directly as origin works as expected, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Did you set up an A-Record as an alias to the ALB? Does that record work independently from CloudFront, i.e. can you reach the website when you access it via the DNS name?

Comment: No, the A record does not work because it is a public hosted zone but without my owning its domain. That was my question. I didn't want to register a domain.

Comment: Well then of course it's not going to work :D - a public hosted zone without a domain pointing to it requires the client to explicitly know about the specific DNS servers that are responsible for this public hosted zone. That's not how DNS or CloudFront work. Added a sentence to make that clear.

Comment: I was just hoping that AWS CloudFront would first check the name sever of the account and that that might be enough.

Comment: That would be a very complex implementation with no real benefits. Creating a subdomain and delegating that to the public hosted zone shouldn't be a big deal, you already seem to have a domain set up that you're using with CloudFront.